# tf Dataset is incompatible with the model dimensions: input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a feed forward dense neural network with 33 input neurons and 3200 output neurons
The input data is in the form dataframe of 216 rows and 33 column and output dataframe of 216 rows and 3200 columns. Next I make a tf dataset with the two dataframes with the follwoing command

```
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input.values, output.T.values))
```

This results in a tf Dataset with following information

```
TakeDataset shapes: ((33,), (3200,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)
```

Following is how I design my layers

```
    model1=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(800,input_shape=(33,),activation='relu'))
    model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(800,activation='tanh'))
    model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000,activation='tanh'))
    model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3200))
```

But when I try to fit the model with the dataset as shown above I encounter the following error

```
Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: 
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 33 but received input with shape [33, 1]
```

But to me the dimensions look fine. Please suggest how to get the code to run

Comment: It's strange that the example here works without any problem https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/174#issuecomment-555815656

Comment: ok I got it. you have to "batch" the dataset, e.g. `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y)).batch(2)`